# is there an R function for converting a raw input into an .xlsx file?

Tags: r, xlsx, gnupg, raw

So for context I'm trying to decrypt and xlsx file using the gpg package. If I decrypt as_text = TRUE I get an error message with and embedded nul in string.

```r
writexl::write_xlsx(x = data.frame(x = 1:2, y = 1:2),
                    path = "testtemp/test_1/test2.xlsx")

encrypted_xlsx <- gpg::gpg_encrypt(
  data = list.files("testtemp/test_1/",
                    full.names = TRUE,
                    pattern = "xlsx"
  ),
  receiver = "mypublickey"
)

writeLines(
  text = encrypted_xlsx,
  con = "testtemp/test_1/test2.xlsx.gpg"
)

gpg::gpg_import("myprivatekey")
decrypted_file <- gpg::gpg_decrypt(
  data = "testtemp/test_1/test2.xlsx.gpg",
  verify = FALSE,
  as_text = FALSE
)

xl <- readxl::read_xlsx(path = rawConnection(decrypted_file))
```

What I've tried in the last line doesn't work but hopefully conveys what I'm trying to achieve.

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          4
minor          0.2
year           2020
month          06
day            22
svn rev        78730
language       R
version.string R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
nickname       Taking Off Again

Comment: Why not write the decrypted data into a file on disk, and then pass that file to `read_xlsx`? I don’t think the function supports reading data from memory.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, sorry I'm not quite sure I follow, what kind of file would you suggest saving the decrypted file to, its class is raw.

Comment: An XLSX file, of course. You can use `writeBin` to write raw vectors directly to a file. `filename = tempfile(fileext = '.xlsx'); writeBin(decrypted_file, filename)`.

Comment: Thank you that worked a treat. Do you think I should post this as an answer or close the question?

Comment: Please go ahead and post it as an answer. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this was to write the decrypted output from gpg:gpg_decrypt to file.

```r
filename = tempfile(fileext = '.xlsx') #create temp file with xlsx suffix
writeBin(decrypted_file, filename)     #write data to file

xl <- readxl::read_xlsx(path = filename)

print(xl)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     2
```

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph for the answer.